# Custom styling with scss for react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, sass, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm building a React app using react-bootstrap. I want to customize react-bootstrap components how can I achieve this?

I followed a short tutorial on the create react app page and was able to override the default variables like primary, secondary etc. I have imported the `bootstrap.scss` end of the file as well.

```
className = "btn-primary btn-sm"

<Button variant="primary" size="sm">
        Primary
 </Button>
```

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: $primary;
  width: 40px;


  &:hover {
    background-color: var(--color-white);
    border: var(--btn-primary-border);

    span {
      color: $primary;
    }
  }

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

I expected my above styles to be applied but it's not applying. Only the background color is applied.

If anyone still looking for an answer this is what I did and it's working for me.

```
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "your custom.css" here
```

This will override the bootstrap styles

Answer (score 14):

It basically boils down to the following steps:

1. Download bootstrap using `npm install react-bootstrap`
2. Install SASS pre-processor (https://sass-lang.com/install)
3. Create a scss file for overriding bootstrap's `_variables.scss` (make sure the path to `_functions.scss`, `_variables.scss`, `_mixins.scss` and `bootstrap.scss` is correct)

```css
/* stylesheet.scss */

@import "bootstrap/scss/functions"; 
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";

/* Your customizations here */

$theme-colors: (
  primary: red;
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

4. Transpile your `stylesheet.scss` to `stylesheet.css` and add a reference to your head section like so: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">`

Here are some links that should help you get started:

1. [How to customize bootstrap](https://uxplanet.org/how-to-customize-bootstrap-b8078a011203)
2. [Theming Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/)

Comment: Hi I was able to override the color but I couldn't get the hover color. It's still default bootstrap styles being applied

Comment: Try overriding `$link-hover-color` and please up-vote or accept if my answer was helpful. Also have a look at the `_variables.scss` file for the elements you can override,

Comment: I did try override the hover color didn't work so I decided to just override the whole bootstrap files.

Answer (score 5):

For bootstrap variables override:

```
// Override Bootstrap Variables.
// For example: $grid-gutter-width-base:  20px;
// For example: $grid-gutter-width: 20px;

@import "bootstrap-overrides";

//Bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints";
```

For custom styling at a component: you will need to import bootstrap at the beginning of the file

```
// Bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints";
```

and after that, you can apply your styling.

Comment: I did as you said and still the same thing

Comment: where did you call the compiled .css file?

Comment: Also, where did you define the color variables?

Comment: I'm using create react app with node-sass to compile so I cannot see the compiled css (I dont know where atleast) I defined variables in main.scss file

Comment: Check this: https://scotch.io/starters/react/adding-sass-to-create-react-app-applications

Comment: I know how to add the sass to cra project, I don't know how to override bootstrap components seperately. Thank you though for the link

Comment: You cannot override everything in bootstrap, but you can create new classes with the characteristics you want to use. I agree with the @Matze, take a look at the bootstrap _variables.scss first

Comment: I updated my initial answer! Check it please :) I hope that helps you!

Comment: Can you please tell me what is bootstrap-variables?

Comment: This is it --> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss

Answer (score 3):

@Matze's method doesn't seem to be working properly but (+1) for helping me find the solution. For example, you can't set border-radius and also color change doesn't have effect on all the components.

By using command line, navigate to your project and run this `npm install --save node-sass`

Afterwards:

```
/* index.scss */

$theme-colors: (
  "primary": red
);

$border-radius: 10rem;

@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

/* The rest of your styles can go below */
```

Now you can just open your `App.js` or `index.js` and add `import './index.scss'`.

```
// index.js

import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

import './index.scss'

import App from "./components/App"

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```